# Using ggmap mapdist() with R

Tags: r, tableau-api, ggmap

I am trying to find distance between two points using ggmap in Tableau. I get an error that the result returned by the script is of an unknown type. I tried using SCRIPT_STR() but that does not work as well. Below is a sample test code I am trying to use.

```
SCRIPT_REAL("library('ggplot2');library('ggmap');mapdist('11040',.arg1)[5]",'10041')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you closed the `mapdist()` function before giving it the `to` argument (i.e., the closing ')' following `.arg1`)

In R, you would have:

```
library(ggmap)
mapdist('11040','10041')
```